# Updating child properties in Entity Framework TPH

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm new to inheritance with EF in C#/MVC, and I'm trying to update a subclass's navigation property but can't figure out how to do so. The subclass inherits from the parent class, obviously, and it has its own EF mapping specified. I have to update the DB using the parent type, otherwise nothing is pushed to the DB (no error is thrown though). Using the parent class, however, doesn't expose the child properties so I can't update them to even push to the DB.

What is the proper way to handle subclass-specific properties in EF?

This is more of a general question than one specific to my issue, but here's the code that doesn't work.

```
// get the existing task using the model posted from view,
// convert it to child class (GetTaskById returns parent class)
PETask task = _projectService.GetTaskById(model.Id).ConvertToET();
var proj = _projectService.GetById(model.ProjectId);

// error checking

if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    // use AutoMapper to convert the posted data to entity, passing task as
    // a parameter to preserve proxies
    task = model.ToEntity(task);

    if (model.SOId.HasValue)
    {
        SalesOrder so = _salesOrderService.GetByOrderId(model.SOId.Value);
        task.SalesOrderId = so.Id;
        task.SalesOrder = so;
    }

    _projectService.Update(task);
    // all information is correct, including a proxy for the SalesOrder property
    // and the actual SalesOrderId, but the DB is not updated. no error is thrown.
}
```

Comment: Please show your current code structure what you have so far.

Comment: @Developer I've added it to the OP.